# filtering facebook campaigns by insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook Graph API and I can't find the way how to filter campaigns based in their spend. This currently the filtering formula I'm using.

```
act_xxxxxxx/campaigns?fields=name,status,insights{spend},start_time,stop_time&filtering=[{'field':'insights.spend','operator':'GREATER_THAN','value':'0'}]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a report of how many campaigns spent more/equal/less than certain amount, all along the insights data.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'spend' instead of 'insights.spend'.

Comment: it returns an error that the field spend doesn't exist in the list of available fields.

Comment: I am using Python FB SDK, in the SDK this filter works {'field':'spend','operator':'GREATER_THAN','value':my_min_spend}. I'm getting insights from the Account object (my_account.get_insights_async(...)), but I am able to specify any desired level ('ad','adset', or 'campaign'), and it works. I can only suggest that you try 'campaign.spend', or resort to SDK instead of direct http calls.